# Use a resized column or split table in the database

Tags: php, mysql, json, database

I want to store the following data in the MySql database (data for notifications):

- id: VARCHAR(10)
- from_id: VARCHAR(10)
- to_id: VARCHAR(10)
- type: int(2)
- type_info: (The problem in this column)
- date : TIMESTAMP

Knowing that the column `type_info` determines its content according to the content of column `type` where I have 4 cases:

- if type = 1  type_info will be empty
- if type = 2  type_info = id1
- if type = 3  type_info = id1/id2
- if type = 4  type_info = id1/id2/id3

Notes:

- -id1,id2 and id3 are VARCHAR(10) (are id of comment,reply,page.....)
- -To extract the values (id1,id2 and id3) i use explode() function on / (PHP)
- -The column **type_info** does not need to update its content. All I need is INSERT and only SELECT
- -I fetch data as gson.

So my question is: In order to increase the query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE date > dateValue`  speed, do I keep the table design the same or is there more efficient design?

If I divided the Table into 4 tables by **type** column, would it be better?

notification table:

```
  id/from_id/to_id/type/date
```

Type_1 table:

```
notfication_i/id1
```

Type_2 table:

```
notfication_i/id1/id2
```

Type_3 table:

```
notfication_i/id1/id2/id3
```

Note: consider only the best table design that increases the query speed above

Is this design suitable?

[image: database design]

Thanks :)

Comment: MySQL or SQL server? They are two different database engines. Is the question really related to both?

Comment: Without  doubt, as this is a relational database, you should split the columns into 3 foreign keys, and set up suitable indexes on each column.

Comment: The special E database with types including VARCHARE and TIMESTEMP. Seriously though, what @TomC said. One value per column in a row. Use joins frequently and often.

Comment: @Alex MySQL server

Comment: @TomC I think you have the answer. Can you add some explanation or an example and I will accept it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer - it is bad practice to embed multiple data items into a single column. As your data contains a list of foreign keys into multiple different table, you should create the individual columns, one for each potential foreign key.

Each column will have its own index allowing rapid lookup of each data type of data without having to manipulate the data using string functions.

The overhead of having 3 potentially empty columns will be negligible.